# Recover certificate & key from app.manifest

Tags: .net

Due to some data loss I was unable to recover some files, like my certificate and private key. I do, however, have the app.manifest. Inside it, I have a `KeyInfo` section which contains RSAKeyValue, Modulus, Exponent, X509Data, and X509Data.

Is there any way to create a PFX and key files from this? I usually just specify the key in Visual Studio but am hoping I can recover it somehow from the app.manifest file...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The manifest only contains the signature and the public key. If there was a way to recover the private key from that file, then anyone could sign their application with your certificate, which would defeat the whole purpose.